# Changing object that is calling a method pass as delegate in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, delegates

Here is my case, I have a Library that have many methodes and have one entry point. I do not have acces to library source code.

Library has methods

```
Class A
 List<int> Methode1(int);
 List<int> Methode2(int);
 List<int> Methode3(int);
```

I have some code that look like that:

```
T CallSomethingInLibrary<T>(T defaultValue, Func<int, T>funcLib, int input)
{
  if(defaultValue==null|| globalFlagDataSourceAsGchanged==true)
  {
   defaultValue=funcLib(input)
  }
  return defaultValue;
}
```

Use:

```
static A nameOfInstance = new A();
List<in> resultOfLib = CallSomethingInLibrary(defaultValue,nameOfInstance.Methode1,8);
```

The problem is that I don't want to call the method on A I want to call it on a different instance. I have a globale list of instance because number of object that talk to library are limited to 10 at the same time. defaultValue:

```
SemaphoreSlim Semaphore1  = new SemaphoreSlim(4);   

T CallSomethingInLibrary<T>(T defaultValue, Func<int, T>funcLib, int input)
{
  if(defaultValue==null|| globalFlagDataSourceAsGchanged==true)
  {
   Semaphore1.Wait();
   A available=GetAvailableInstance();
   defaultValue=available.funcLib(input);
   Semaphore1.Release();
  }
  return defaultValue;
}
```

I know I could do that with Invoke but I like the fact that I can know at compile time if Methode1 is a member of A and as the good signature

And the reason for CallSomethingInLibrary to exist is because I don't want to copy past those lines evrywhere.

```
if(DosomeValidation())
  {
   Semaphore1.Wait();
   A available=GetAvailableInstance();
   ...
```

It is also use as some kind of custom LazyInstantiation that does more.

Thank you

Comment: you can make `Methode1` and others `static` so you don't need reference to use them.

Comment: Can you clarify the question and fix the redacted code? Right now you're mixing Methode1/methode1 (fair enough) and return types List<int>/int. You also ignore available.funcLib()'s return value in the second example. A less abstract (and somewhat working) example would help.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I do not have access to Library class A.

Comment: @BenjaminPodszun I solved some issue with the code Is that better

Comment: The code is still hairy in places, but if I understand you correctly then Rob answered that quite nicely already. If CallSomethingInLibrary is really just wrapping another call with boiler plate, pass in a function expecting the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your method as so:

```
T CallSomethingInLibrary<T>(Func<A, T> funcLib)
{
    if(DosomeValidation())
    {
        A available=GetAvailableInstance();
        funcLib(available);
        //Where is the return here??
    }
    else
    {
        return new List<int>()
    }
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
CallSomethingInLibrary(instance => instance.methode1(8));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "I have some code that look like" doesn't compile. You can't have a return of `new List<int>()` when the return type is `T`. You also have to return something on the `true` branch of the `if`.

So, to make your original code work you need something like this:

```
T DoSomeValidation<T>(Func<int, T> funcLib, Func<int, T> funcDefault, int input)
{
    if (DoSomeValidation())
    {
        return funcLib(input);
    }
    else
    {
        return funcDefault(input);
    }
}
```

Then you'd call it like so:

```
A nameOfInstance = new A();
List<int> resultOfLib = CallSomethingInLibrary(nameOfInstance.methode1, n => new List<int>(), 8);
```

That works.

Beyond that it gets a bit confusing with what you're asking. It's trivial for you to call this function with a different instance of `A`. It would just be this:

```
A available = GetAvailableInstance();
List<int> resultOfLib = CallSomethingInLibrary(available.methode1, n => new List<int>(), 8);
```

There's nothing in this code that prevents you from calling it from any type - so long as the compiler can resolve the call down to a `Func<int, T>`.

You need to clarify what you mean by "I want to call it on a different instance".

Comment: I clarified my question and explained more why I need such code. Thank you